# loading data form txt into an external hive table and rows with a special characters are being inserted

Tags: hadoop, text, hive, special-characters

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE EUROPEANSITES(
SITEID STRING,
SITES_IN_COUNTRY STRING,
EMP_INCO_INCNTRY STRING,
PC_IN_COUNTRY STRING,
PREFERRED_WAN_PROVIDER STRING,
REG_CODE STRING,
NAF_CODE_REV2 STRING,
NUTS2_CODE STRING,
NUTS2_DESC STRING,
NUTS3_CODE STRING,
NUTS3_DESC STRING,
NUTS4_CODE STRING,
NUTS4_DESC STRING,
TURNOVER_CODE STRING,
TURNOVER_LOCAL STRING,
TURNOVER_EUROS STRING,
VAT_CODE STRING,
NACE1_CODE STRING,
NACE1_DESC STRING,
NACE2_CODE STRING,
NACE2_DESC STRING,
NACE3_CODE STRING,
NACE3_DESC STRING,
NACE4_CODE STRING,
NACE4_DESC STRING,
ENT_NACE3_CODE STRING,
ENT_NACE3_DESC STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
ESCAPED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
TBLPROPERTIES ('skip.header.line.count' = '1')
;
```

this is the script I am using to load a text file with '\t' delimited  but when I load the data and query the table I see alternate rows with special character .
 When I verified the file I dont see any special character.

the data in the table looks like this :

[Please click here to see how the data in the table looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Owm9D.png)

Comment: First guess is you've got something after your newline.

Comment: Sure, I will check that so if have a special character after my new line is there a way I can escape it.

Answer (score -1):

I tried cleaning up the file and it worked, i used this command :
sed $'s/[^[:print:]\t]//g' filename.csv> tgt_filename.csv
then I used openserde to avoid the "".